# How to add Download Button on every post of Facebook via android app?

Tags: android, facebook, download

I have a live android application on play store. In my app, I can post textual data, links on Facebook. Now, I want to add a custom button similar to Facebook share/like buttons on posting every post that button will get displayed below the post. And it will be redirected to play store on my app page on click of that button.

So the people will get to the app on just single click.

**Simply, I want show DOWNLOAD BUTTON on every post on Facebook through my app.**

Format of Facebook Post like below:

Facebook post : Hello friends, Good Morning + Download Button (through my app)

Comment: just use market://details?id=your.package.name

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Can you please elaborate it so that It will help me to get it completed because I already found it on SO

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot prefill the text for the user, doing that is a violation of the Platform Policy.
2. There's no method through the Graph API or the Share Dialogs to create a download button for your app. You can create a mobile app install ad instead.